# Can I save repeater textbox value to single column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Now am using repeater control and create three labels and corresponding textbox. I want to save this value in single table column value. what can I do? I don't have any idea to save. please help me and give me an example also.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's hard to understand your question. When you say table do you mean a datagridview?

Comment: In here you always need to show [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I assume by single table column you mean single column in database.

Just run a foreach loop on your repeater on your Save event & reference each item of the repeater, save each item's desired value in a string & add a comma separator, something like this. Hope it helps

```
 string textToSave;  
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater_items.Items)
    {
          //Fetch your controls here
         textToSave+=yourcontrol.Text + ",";
    }
// Save textToSave to your database here
```